# Error when call method from another class in android

Tags: android, button, methods

i have 2 class. One is MainBaby.java and it contains:

```
public class MainBaby extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public MainBaby(Context context){
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MainBaby(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      init();
}

public MainBaby(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      init();
}

public void init(){
    // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events

    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    // create the game loop thread
    thread = new ThreadBaby(getHolder(), this);

    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setDither(true);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    p.setStrokeWidth(50);

    setFocusable(true);

}

public void callMe(){

    Log.v("tag", "the button successfully pressed");
}   
}
```

this class in inflated in main.xml

```
<AbsoluteLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <coba.gesture.Main
    android:id="@+id/LayoDalam"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

and i want to call method callMe() at cobaGesture.java like this:

public class CobaGesture extends Activity {
    MainBaby mb;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    ImageButton resetBut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    resetBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mb.callMe();
        }
    });      
}
```

but when i click the button, the application was force closed and here's the logcat:

```
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at coba.gesture.CobaGesture$1.onClick(CobaGesture.java:41)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-30 10:55:58.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(704):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what does it means? and how to solve it?

thank you in advance.

UPDATE!
here's the edited code and the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initial object with the correct context (in this case, it is your activity). So it is:

```
  mb = new MainBaby(CobaGesture.this);
OR:
  mb = new MainBaby(getApplicationContext());
```

Put this code into onClick event or onCreate, so you can use **mb.callMe();**

All about the context is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572553/719212) and from [Android document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
mb.callMe();
```

Is not institiated thats the reason of the error. In other words, you are using a variable that points to nothing or Null.
If you want to use other classes in your code your should declare it first.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 MainBaby mb = new MainBaby(); //This initiates the variable correctly.
 mb.callMe();
}
```

Comment: when i used the code above, it display error.
it says "add argument to match MainBaby(context)", "add argument to match MainBaby(context, attrs)", "add argument to match MainBaby(context, attrs, defStyle)"

Comment: I didn't pay attention that the MainBaby class had parameters in the constructor, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the object mb as **mb=new MainBaby(CobaGesture.this);** inside the oncreate method

Comment: i've used the code above, it display error. it says "add argument to match MainBaby(context)", "add argument to match MainBaby(context, attrs)", "add argument to match MainBaby(context, attrs, defStyle)" –

Comment: i've posted the image. please check it out.

Comment: see the edited code, Mainbaby has the contructor with paramater, so while creating the object we have to pass context of this CabaGesture class.

Answer (score -2):

callme() is a method of android which is called when in view when we pressed any button .
just put this below method in activity which contain atleast one button and run your project .

```
 public void callMe(View view){

            Log.e("tag", "the button successfully pressed");
        }
```