# How to call a method from another class ? Method has to modify the Image View(Variable) android

Tags: android, uiimageview

I have a class in which i have defined XML file by set Content View(R.layout.A) and defined it components i.e. images imp = (Image view)find View by id(...) now I want to modify this image on click of button it should call the method from another class ...
my problem is about Image View variable I don't know how to deal with this variable (int,float,char are easy for me) 
 I have referred this links 
[Error when call method from another class in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809813/error-when-call-method-from-another-class-in-android) and [Android Call an method from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787159/android-call-an-method-from-another-class)
 please help me in this matter.....
Thanks in advance....

Comment: post your code, and what you want to do actually? call a method from other call or this method from other class?

Comment: your both class are activity or one of them is just class?

Comment: post your code as saqib said

Comment: My main class 
i have defined image view in that..
now i have created another class and created its object in main class
B b = new B();
now on click of button
I have to access method inside that class B
through that method i have to modify my image view..